# If Else with 2 conditions and using result in the if and else part

Tags: vba, excel, if-statement

I have this code it's supposed to check a certain range in the third column for the value 4 and if a cell has the value 4 it's supposed to check the value of the adjacent cell in the fourth column. 
If this value is smaller than y it's supposed to assign the value 4 to the 5 cells in the 15th column starting in the row in which the 4 was initially found. If it's higher than it should assign it to 8 cells in column 15 starting in the row in which the 4 was initially found.

The problem that keeps occuring is that the cell specification in the `Else` part for example `.Cells(x - 1, a).Value = 5`results in an error. If I only use  the `If` portion it works fine.

```
Sub einfügen()

Dim a As Integer
Dim x As Integer
Dim y As LongLong

a = 15
y = 100000


With ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet

For x = 1 To 112
    If .Cells(x, 3).Value = 4 And ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Cells(x, 3).Offset(0, 1) <= y Then

            .Cells(x - 1, a).Value = 4
            .Cells(x - 2, a).Value = 4
            .Cells(x - 3, a).Value = 4
            .Cells(x - 4, a).Value = 4
            .Cells(x - 5, a).Value = 4
    Else

            .Cells(x - 1, a).Value = 4
            .Cells(x - 2, a).Value = 4
            .Cells(x - 3, a).Value = 4
            .Cells(x - 4, a).Value = 4
            .Cells(x - 5, a).Value = 4
            .Cells(x - 6, a).Value = 4
            .Cells(x - 7, a).Value = 4
            .Cells(x - 8, a).Value = 4


   End If


   Next

End With
End Sub
```

Comment: `Cells` needs a row greater or equal than 1. In your case `x -1` is 0 and there is no row 0

Comment: oh that was very obvious...

Comment: That might also happen in your if branch. You have to be careful when using cells and have to make sure the values in the brackets are positive.

Answer (score 0):

not so clear to me what should *"starting in the row in which the 4 was initially found."* actually mean, so I assumed it should start from current row `x` downwards

furthermore, based on your narrative, you have to split the first IF two conditions into two, otherwise your code would always try and fill some cells with 4's

here's the snippet you may want to try:

```
With ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet
    For x = 1 To 112
        If .Cells(x, 3).Value = 4 Then '" if a cell has the value 4"
            If .Cells(x, 3).Offset(0, 1) <= y Then '"check the value of the adjacent cell in the fourth column. If this value is smaller than y..."
                .Cells(x, a).Resize(5).Value = 4 '"assign the value 4 to the 5 cells in the 15th column starting in the row in which the 4 was initially found."
            Else '"If it's higher"
                .Cells(x, a).Resize(8).Value = 4 '"assign it to 8 cells in column 15 starting in the row in which the 4 was initially found."
            End If
        End If
    Next
End With
```